# The secret key cannot be read even I already provided in .env file

Tags: node.js

**controllers/user.js**

```
router.post("/login-user", catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next) => {
    try{
        const { email, password } = req.body

        if(!email || !password){
            return next(new ErrorHandler("Please provide all the fields", 400))
        }

        const user = await User.findOne({email}).select("+password")
        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler("User doesn't exists!", 400));
        }
    
        const isPasswordValid = await user.comparePassword(password);
    
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
            return next(
                new ErrorHandler("Please provide the correct information", 400)
            );
        }

        sendToken(user, 201, res)
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500))
    }
}))
```

**utils/jwtToken.js**

```
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = user.getJwtToken()
    console.log(token)
    
    const options = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: true,
    }

    res.status(statusCode).cookie("token", token, options).json({
        success: true,
        user,
        token,
    })
}

module.exports = sendToken
```

**middlewares/auth.js**

```
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler.js")
const catchAsyncErrors = require("./catchAsyncErrors.js")
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")

const User = require("../models/user.js")

require("dotenv").config()

exports.isAuthenticated = catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next) => {
    const {token} = req.cookies

    if(!token){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Please login to continue", 401))
    }

    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)

    req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id)
    console.log(req.user)
    next()
})
```

I am trying to login the user and I do not understand why the error message shows that `Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value` even I had a value already in the .env config file. May I ask are there any solutions to check whether the secret key is provided?

Comment: can you please log the process.env and check if it has the value properly?

Comment: Where can I log them out to check the values?

Comment: auth.js, above where you are actually using it

Comment: which command are you using to run the server?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it return `undefined` because of the scope of the `.env` file, I am faced this issue when i stated server on debug mode in vs code. I resolved it by specifying the `.env` file's absolute path in `config` options

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: '/home/...'});
```